# Strftime date change with php and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, strtotime

```
<?php
    //run a select query to my latest 1 item
    include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
    // This block grabs the whole list for viewing
$dynamicList= "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $title = $row["title"];
             $author = $row["author"];
             $category = $row["category"];
             $article = $row["article"];
            // $postdate = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["postdate"]));
              $postdate = $row["postdate"];
             //Seperate so it's easier to see what i'm working with here.
             $short = substr(strip_tags($article), 0, 400);

             $dynamicList .= '<ul>
<li>
<div class="wrapFirstRowBlog">
    <div class="postDate">'.$postdate.'</div>
    <div class="nextToDate">
    <div class="blogTitle"><h3><a href="blog.php?id='.$id.'">'.$title.'</a></h3></div>
    <div class="author">written by '.$author.' for the '.$category.' section.</div>
    <div class="socialNetwork"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="blogPreview">
<img class="blogLeft" src="../blog_images/'.$id.'.jpg" width="150" height"150" alt="'.$title.'"/>'.$short.'...<a href="http://www.moniquetrinidadjewelry.com/images/new-images/read-more.png"><img src="http://www.moniquetrinidadjewelry.com/images/new-images/read-more.png" alt="read more of this post" /></a>
</div>
</li>
</ul>';
    }
} else {
    $dynamicList = 'Nothing posted yet...check back soon!';
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

I've tried many combinations searched everywhere here and I can do what I'm trying to do with it begin within my script. I'm trying to convert the date to simply show date. My mysql reading is

```
2013-06-03 00:18:32
```

and I'd like to simply cut that to show only the date and not time. I can't seem to figure out how to do it when it is within my script. I've tried

```
$postdate = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["postdate"]));
```

which is a containment of the row and can't figure it out. At what point should I be outputting these changes and any reference as to why would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [**`date`**](http://php.net/manual/it/function.date.php) function

```
$postdate = date("m d, Y", strtotime($row["postdate"]));
```

This will store in your variable `$postdate` your date

```
06 03, 2013
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/KZ9UAx)

Comment: That's excellent! Thanks a ton. I've been researching here forever trying to figure that out. So I get a better understanding...at what point is the conversion being made? Right as it is called?

Comment: @HireLogo conversion has been done while you call date and strtotime function, you can either print as in my working sample or store in a variable to print later as your code suggest. If you think answer is correct please accept it to help people in yhe future with similar problems